# Mysql-installer showing error : Memoy could not be written

Tags: mysql, database, windows-installer, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install MySql Workbench and download **mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.13.0.msi**.
When i run this file i got following error:

> "The instruction at 0x6d4424ff referenced memory at 0x6d4424ff. The
>   memory could not be written"
>   Click Ok to terminate the program.

**My system config :**
Windows i7 64 bit machine with 8 GB RAM and 4gb graphics.

Anyone knows the solution of this problem???

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if you have installed multiple "mysql installer"(check in "uninstall or change a program" in control panel). If yes, remove them all and install only one instance. Now even if the above error(mentioned in question) comes, (don't worry) just search the installer in start menu and open it. A  mysql installer window will appear, On right side you will see an option add, just click on it and proceed. In this way you will add a new server.